# How to use Python regex to remove all except pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a pandas dataframe with some rating values in single column.
My goal is to extract some markers to new series.
I have a list of unique values like this:

```
['nan' 'AAA' 'AA+' 'AA' 'A+' 'A-' 'AA-' 'BB+' 'BBB' 'BBB-' 'A' 'BB-'
 'BBB+' 'B+' 'BB' 'B' 'A *-' 'A- *-' 'B-' 'CCC+' 'CCC' 'CCC-' 'CC' 'SD'
 'CCC+ *-' 'BB *-' 'BB- *-' 'B *-' 'B+ *-' 'B- *-' 'BBB+ *-' 'CCC- *-'
 'BBB- *-' 'BB+ *-' 'A+ *-' 'BBB *-' 'AAA *-' 'AA *-' 'AA- *-' 'NR']
```

So, I'm trying to use additional patterns `' *-'` and `' *+'` before it's removing to create a new dataframe column with values `'-'` (for ratings that ends with `' *-'`), `'+'` (for `' *+'` ending) and `''` or `nan` for other rating types.

Simple removing is quite clear for me (something like `'( \*.)'` pattern in `re.sub`), but the question is to pick out markers before doing this.
I'm not a specialist in regex, so I spend a plenty of time trying to explore `re.sub` function with patterns like `'[^(\*.)]'`, `'[^(\*[\+\-])]'` with no result.

Comment: Your _unique values_ will be concatenated to just one long string.

Comment: I guess this regex ```r'([*]?[+-]?)'``` will do the trick.

Comment: post the initial dataframe and expected result

Comment: You do not need to remove all except pattern since there is `str.extract()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':['nan', 'AAA', 'AA+', 'AA', 'A+', 'A-', 'AA-', 
'BB+', 'BBB', 'BBB-', 'A', 'BB-', 'BBB+', 'B+', 'BB', 'B', 'A *-',
 'A- *-', 'B-', 'CCC+', 'CCC', 'CCC-', 'CC', 'SD', 'CCC+ *-', 'BB *-',
 'BB- *-', 'B *-', 'B+ *-', 'B- *-', 'BBB+ *-', 'CCC- *-',
 'BBB- *-', 'BB+ *-', 'A+ *-', 'BBB *-', 'AAA *-', 'AA *-', 'AA- *-', 'NR']})

df['new_col'] = [re.search('([-+])$', x).group(0) 
    if re.search('([-+])$', x) else '' for x in df.col0]
```

Which will give

```
       col0 new_col
0       nan        
1       AAA        
2       AA+       +
3        AA        
4        A+       +
5        A-       -
6       AA-       -
7       BB+       +
8       BBB        
9      BBB-       -
10        A        
11      BB-       -
12     BBB+       +
13       B+       +
14       BB        
15        B        
16     A *-       -
17    A- *-       -
18       B-       -
19     CCC+       +
20      CCC        
21     CCC-       -
22       CC        
23       SD        
24  CCC+ *-       -
25    BB *-       -
26   BB- *-       -
27     B *-       -
28    B+ *-       -
29    B- *-       -
30  BBB+ *-       -
31  CCC- *-       -
32  BBB- *-       -
33   BB+ *-       -
34    A+ *-       -
35   BBB *-       -
36   AAA *-       -
37    AA *-       -
38   AA- *-       -
39       NR
```

What I do is loop through the rows of the column, then check if the last character is a `+` or a `-`. If so it puts it in group 0 which I call. If a `+` or `-` is not found, a `None` object is returned which is evaluated as `False` and '' is returned instead.  This list can be assigned to a new column.

If you are looking for the string literal `*-` and `*+` then you need to make this slight change.

```
df['new_col'] = [re.search(r'\*([-+])$', x).group(0) 
    if re.search(r'\*([-+])$', x) else '' for x in df.col0]
```

For what it's worth, I tested all of this is Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second variant is what I need to go further!
Also thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew for alternative solution